# Laravel Controller member variable

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

Is there any possibility in laravel to keep the state of the controller object?

In every example I found, the controller looks the following way:

```
 class MyController extends Controller {
      public function getView(){ //return the view }
      public function postData() { //save the data }
 }
```

What I would do is to call a service which loads specific data from my data base and return it to the view. In the example above this should be done within the getView() function. What if I need the same data in my postData() function.. Then I have to make another database call in the postData function. It is not possible to have a member variable in 'MyController' and to load the data only once for the class because of routing in laravel. When I call via routing the getView function I get another instance of MyController than I get if I call postData. Is there a possibility to call a specific function only once for the whole controller and to get access to this values from all the functions within the controller?

Comment: Can't you simply call `getView()` directly in `postData()` and return it?

Comment: Use caching then.

Comment: Depending on what `postData()` is doing I'll be very careful with using cache. You might want to ensure that you have the latest data available from your database on form submission (assuming your `post` prefix means that). Exercise caution.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a possibility to call a specific function only once for the
>   whole controller and to get access to this values from all the
>   functions within the controller?

As per my understanding it it not possible. Actually any function of controller is being called via routes. When your any route has been called every time the new object of controller is being created. But it has other way of round. You can use Cache. You can implement it as below:

- Call to your specific function of controller.
- Get the data from the database.
- Store it in Cache for other functions.
- In other functions check is data available in Cache? then get from Cache else call your database function to get the data.

Simply in coding as below:

```
Use Cache;
 class MyController extends Controller {
      public function getView(){ 
        $data = call_to_database_and_returned_data();
        Cache::put('data',$data,120);
        return the view 
      }

      public function postData() { 
         $data = null;
         if(Cache::has('data')) {
            $data = Cache::get('data');
         } else {
            $data = call_to_database_and_returned_data();
            Cache::put('data',$data,120);
         }
      }
 }
```

Syntax Description:

```
Cache::put('name_to_save_data',$your_variable_to_save,for_number_minutes);
```

Comment: Is there any other way to keep the state of an Controller object? I.e. when creating a Wizard.. each Wizard Step would be a Controller. But also in this case its only possible to keep values except in putting them in the Session. Would there be another Solution which is not session nor cache?

Comment: There may be a solution but I am not sure. According to me to achieve this we have to make changes in LARAVEL internal structure because for every route LARAVEL is creating the new instance of that respective controller. To achieve your problem we have to create SINGLETON INSTANCE of controller. So at initial first time you will call function which will set the value to class property from database. Hence next time any other function of that controller class has been called you will already have the values in the respective assigned class property.